# Passing Variable to another document Via Import

Tags: python, python-import, python-3.8

So I have 2 documents:

**document_a.py** and  **document_b.py**

**document_a.py** has the following code:

```
from document_b import hello

age = 31

hello('Eric')
```

**document_b.py** has the following code:

```
def hello(name):
    print('Hello',name)
    print('age:',age)
```

How do I get the **age** variable on **document_a.py** to pass to **def hello(name):** on **document_b.py**?

Answer (score 0):

You've set it up in a way that makes it impossible, so something has to change.

You can change the function:

```
def hello(name, age):
    print('Hello',name)
    print('age:',age)
```

And call it with `hello('Eric', age)`.

Another alternative would be to define a global age in `document_b`:

```
age = 0
def hello(name):
    print('Hello',name)
    print('age:',age)
```

And then `document_a` should look like this:

```
import document_b
document_b.age = 31
document_b.hello('Eric')
```

Comment: Thank you.  I dont know why I just didnt use the first option you gave.  I must of had a blonde moment. :)

Comment: @BigEfromDaBX no problem! I'd appreciate an upvote and you can click the checkmark to accept the answer if you found it helpful